# Difference op amp with imperfections -- maximum dc offset

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
[image]
How may I find the maximum dc offset due to the imperfections listed in this question?

For \$I_B\$:

I know \$I_{b1}=0.5\mu A+0.1\mu/2=0.55\mu A,I_{b2}=0.5\mu A-0.1\mu/2=0.45\mu A\$

This yielded \$v_+=-0.45mV\$

Hence,

\$0.45mV/R_1-(-0.45mV-v_o)/R_2=0.55\mu A\$

Which yielded \$v_o=0.505V\$

For \$V_{OS}\$:

\$v_+=4mV\$

Hence,

\$-4mV/R_1=(4mV-v_o)/R_2\$

Which yielded \$v_o=0.4V\$

For \$I_{OS}\$:

\$v_+=-0.99mV\$

Hence,

\$-0.99mV/R_1=(-0.99mV-v_o)/R_2\$

Which yielded \$v_o=0.098V\$

Does this make sense? If it doesn't, where am I erring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see. To be able to find \$V_O\$ due to \$V_{OS}\$ we need to solve this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEc5Yn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hence,

$$V_O = V_{OS}* \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)= 0.404V$$

Now the bias current:

\$I_B = \frac{I_P+I_N}{2}\$

\$I_O = I_P-I_N \$

Where \$I_P\$ is a Non-Inverting input bias current and \$I_N\$ - Inverting Input bias current.

From this I get:

\$ I_P = I_B-0.5I_O = 0.45µA \$

and

\$ I_N = I_B+0.5I_O = 0.55µA \$

And the circuit diagram will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Przi.png)</sup>

And finally using superposition, we have:

The voltage at \$V_P\$ node is

$$ V_P = -I_P*R_3||R_4$$

and the output voltage is \$V_O' = V_p*A_v\$ and the Non-Inverting gain is \$A_v = (1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}) = \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}\$ therefore

$$V_O' = -I_P*R_3||R_4*\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}= -I_P \frac{R_3||R_4(R_1+R_2)}{R_1} = -450mV $$

And for the second case, we have

$$V_O'' = I_N*R_2 = 550mV $$

And finally

$$V_O = V_O'+V_O'' = -450mV + 550mV = 100mV$$ due to the input bias current.

Therefore the maximum output DC offset voltage is:

\$Vo = 404mV+100mV = 504mV\$ or \$304mV\$ is we assumed that the bias current is entring the op amp input.

Comment: Just one question - why isn't the contribution to the offset by \$I_{OS}\$ accounted for? Is it strictly because it's embedded within the  \$I_P,I_N\$ and calculation above?

Comment: Yes, I include \$I_{OS}\$effect in \$I_P, I_N\$ equations.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have counted the offset current twice, and I'm not sure what you're doing with the bias current.

With perfect value resistors (as here), there are three contributions to the output voltage, which add linearly.

1) Offset voltage. This is simply multiplied by the gain, to give about 400mV. You figure out whether the gain is 100 or 101.

2) Offset current. This flows in the feedback resistor, to give 0.1V.

3) Bias current. This is zero, as the resistors are perfectly balanced.

Add the contributions with appropriate signs to get the worst case.

Comment: One of the issues with offset is that it ruins your gain (as the loop will try to now maintain a certain offset in voltages instead of making inputs equal). I don't know how it factors in here. I think it's best to replace the circuit with an ideal OTA, with current sources to ground to represent the input offset and bias curent, and a voltage source at one of the inputs for ofset voltage

Comment: @JorenVaes I have only one word for you, *superposition*!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things.

The gain of the amplifier in this configuration is

\$ V_{out}= \frac {R2} {R1} (V_2 - V_1)\$

The output voltage of the amplifier for \$ V_{os}\$ is quite simply \$ V_{os}  \frac {R2} {R1} \$ so for this amplifier that yields:

\$ 4mV  \cdot\frac {1M} {10k} \$ = +/-400mV (because we do not know which sign Vos will have).

The \$I_{os}\$ term adds another offset to the input of \$ 0.1 \mu A \cdot 10k\$ = 1mV (to a very close approximation), which will also be multiplied by the gain of the amplifier which yields +/-100mV.

That yields a worst case offset (in either direction) of 500mV.